# Magento reindex catalog product flat error: Error in foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, magento

I have an error when I try to reindex Magento 1.7 catalog product flat index (through admin panel or command line).

On the command line I get the following error:

> ```
> Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005
> Can't create table 'databasename.#sql-340a_22a3' (errno: 121)' in
> /var/www/clients/client1/web16/web/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
> ```

When I look in mysql using '`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`', I get the following error:

> ```
> 160830 10:17:09 Error in foreign key constraint creation for table
> `databasename`.`#sql-340a_2160`.
> A foreign key constraint of name 
> `databasename`.`FK_MAGE_MAGE_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_MAGE_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID`
> already exists. (Note that internally InnoDB adds 'databasename'
> in front of the user-defined constraint name.)
> Note that InnoDB's FOREIGN KEY system tables store
> constraint names as case-insensitive, with the
> MySQL standard latin1_swedish_ci collation. If you
> create tables or databases whose names differ only in
> the character case, then collisions in constraint
> names can occur. Workaround: name your constraints
> explicitly with unique names.
> ```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `foreign_key_checks` MySQL option before reindex

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
// job
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that disabling foreign key checks is a good idea as it can lead to corrupted lines. In fact, this error **is** the result of some corrupted lines already.

You may read this thread which is, to me, a better way to resolve this issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/product-flat-data-wont-reindex/354240